# Laravel 5.1: how to fetch on separate table

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5.1, fetch

I want to fetch uploaded data like pdf, jpg, png etc. in my blade that only the users who uploaded that file can view. The uploaded file was in a separate table from the users table but it has a foreign key which is the `user_id`.

This is my Controller:

```
public function store() {

        $file = Request::file('filefield');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Storage::disk('local')->put($file->getFilename().'.'.$extension,  File::get($file));
        $entry = new Fileentry();
        $entry->mime = $file->getClientMimeType();
        $entry->original_filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $entry->filename = $file->getFilename().'.'.$extension;
        $entry->description = Request::input('description');

        $entry->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        $entry->save();

        return redirect('fileentry');


}

public function show($filename){


    $entry = Fileentry::where('filename', '=', $filename)->firstOrFail();
    $file = Storage::disk('local')->get($entry->filename);

    return (new Response($file, 200))
          ->header('Content-Type', $entry->mime);

}
```

And this is my blade.php:

> ```
> @foreach($entries as $entry)
>
>     <div class="col-md-2">
>         <div class="thumbnail"> 
>             <table>
>
>                 <img src="{{route('getentry', $entry->filename ) }}" alt="ALT NAME" class="img-responsive" />
>
>                      <p>{{ $entry->description }} </p>
>                      <p>{{ $entry->user_id }} </p>
>                      <p>{{ $entry->description }} </p>
>
>                      <a href="{{ URL::to('download') }}" download="{{ $entry->original_filename }}">{{ $entry->original_filename }}</a>
>
>             </table>
>
>         </div>
>     </div>
>
> @endforeach
> ```

I would be glad if you guys could help me.

Comment: Please don't post code snippets as images. Copy paste them instead.

Comment: Yes, post the code so that we can easily copy it as needed - images mean we would have to type it all out.

Comment: okay sirs i'm so sorry ... i will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simple fetch your data using the

```
Auth::user()->id ?
```

So in your case:

```
$Files = Fileentry::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

Comment: I already did that but i got the same result it fetch all data from fileentry table T__T

Comment: So do you use Authentications? And got multiple Users? This only works, when you are using an Authentication and every user got his "own" user_id. Then: Are you sure that every different user has his "own" files? Check out in your database for the field "user_id"

Comment: Yes sir i use Authentications... and all my users has it's own files ^^

Comment: Then check out your user_id before fetch with: dd(Auth::user()->id);

Comment: hello sir that's why i've got the same result i put "$Files = Fileentry::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get(); " in a wrong function ^^ ..thank you sir for the help ^^

Comment: I´m glad that i could help you

Answer (score 0):

In your User model create the following method:

```
public function files() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Fileentry')
}
```

You could change the model of the Fileentry, if it is located somewhere else.

Then, in your view, you could do the following:

```
@foreach($user->files as $file)
    {{ $file->description }}
@endforeach
```

More information about relations is in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)